# Merge variable rows into one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have the following data

[image: Data]

and I would like to have it organized by individual parts while merging the parts IDs into a cell

[image: Output]

is there any way of doing this with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=JOIN(", "; TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B; $A$2:$A = E2)))
```

[image: 3]